# In Flutter, how can I check if a mouse device or a touch device?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I check if the device is a touch device or a mouse device?

Using kIsWeb is not sufficient because if using web version of the app on a mobile device kIsWeb returns true, but I need it to return false because it is a touch device.

Checking the platform doesn't work either because if using web version of the app on an iOS device for example returns false for iOS platform check.

Use case - I have two different types of video players for my app. One is suitable for touch devices (you tap to show and hide controls) and one is suitable for mouse devices (controls show when you mouse into the player and hide when you mouse out).

Youtube has the same idea. If I use the youtube app or website on my iPhone I get touch controls. If I use the youtube app or website on my iPad Pro I get touch controls.  If I use the youtube website on my Mac I get mouse controls at all screen sizes (even mobile screen sizes).

So I guess I really just need to know platform on the web. I can get platform if not on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question @jwasher! I had the same issue - a touch and swipe based UI that was great as a native mobile app, great as an single page web app (SPA) on mobile web browsers, but that was weird and clunky for mouse based interactions when the SPA was used in a desktop web browser.

The solution I have settled on is to wrap sensitive widgets in a MouseRegion (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html) to detect mouse activity at runtime, then reacting by augmenting the UI with buttons to provide a mouse focussed way of triggering actions previously only linked to touch triggers.

You could use this to "mouse-enable" individual widgets, or you could wrap the whole app in a MouseRegion, trip a state field when activity was detected then rebuild the widget tree in a substantially different way for point and click users.

This strategy may incur some minor complexity/CPU overhead on devices that will never have a mouse attached (like a smartphone), but the solution will be more flexible than a build or configuration time capability determination. If a user starts the app on a tablet, then puts it in a stand and attaches a bluetooth mouse - it will react appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get your `TargetPlatform` with `Theme.of(context).platform`.
Even on the web, it will give you the underlying platform, so for example it will give you `TargetPlatform.android` even when running in an Android browser. And then since in most cases touch OSes and non-touch OSes are separate, you get a good approximation: android, iOS and Fushia will be touch-based, whereas linux, windows and macos will be mouse-based. Of course, there are edge cases like Windows on Surface devices for example, but in general, those hybrid devices accept a mouse anyway (and most people use it with one). So for me, it's a pretty good approximation, and it works on web and mobile.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Sebastien's answer, we wrote a piece of magic. With it, you can have a widget that only appears on touch-screen devices, on pointer-powered devices, or show a widget or another one depending on the kind of device the user's using. As @Sebastien has said, this is great because it doesn't take into consideration if the user's using a native app or a web, and that's the point. You don't want phone users working on the web to be treated in the same way you would treat a Windows desktop user.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InteractionTypeResponsiveWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  final Widget touchDevices;
  final Widget pointerDevices;

  const InteractionTypeResponsiveWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.touchDevices,
    required this.pointerDevices,
  });

  static bool isTouchDevice(BuildContext context) {
    final platform = Theme.of(context).platform;
    return platform == TargetPlatform.android ||
        platform == TargetPlatform.iOS ||
        platform == TargetPlatform.fuchsia;
  }

  static bool isPointerDevice(BuildContext context) => !isTouchDevice(context);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isTouchDevice(context)) {
      return touchDevices;
    } else {
      return pointerDevices;
    }
  }
}

class OnlyTouchDevicesWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const OnlyTouchDevicesWidget({required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InteractionTypeResponsiveWidget(
      touchDevices: child,
      pointerDevices: SizedBox(),
    );
  }
}

class OnlyPointerDevicesWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const OnlyPointerDevicesWidget({required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InteractionTypeResponsiveWidget(
      touchDevices: SizedBox(),
      pointerDevices: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A device isn't "a mouse device" or "a pointer device". *Events* have an input type--see [Pointer event.kind](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/PointerEvent/kind.html)--but not the whole device. A laptop can have a touch screen, and a tablet can have a stylus or external mouse; an app running in those environments can receive both types of event.

Without knowing what you are trying to accomplish with this classification, is hard to advise on how to accomplish it. Trying to style your UI based on a guess of the primary interaction mode, for instance, is a completely different problem than reacting to a mouse event differently than a touch event.

Comment: I added a use case to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Combined great ideas of @richard-woods and @smorgan as just `MouseRegion` was not enough:

```dart
class FooState extends State<Foo> {
  bool hasMouse = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final child = Bar();

    return hasMouse
        ? _WithMouse(child: child)
        : MouseRegion(
            onHover: (event) {
              if (event.kind == PointerDeviceKind.mouse) {
                setState(() => hasMouse = true);
              }
            },
            child: _WithoutMouse(child: child),
          );
  }
}
```

Tested:

- With mouse: Linux Chrome.
- Without mouse: Android APK, Android Chrome.